# The 'correct' way to share code across TypeScript, nodejs and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, webpack

I want to have a mono repo that contains the following:

- `shared`: a bunch of **TypeScript** classes that can be used ANYWHERE
- `WebClient`: a react web app in **JavaScript** (that needs to use code in `shared`)
- `WebServer`: a **TypeScript** server app for the react app (that also needs to use `shared` code)

The key issue is: how to I define, configure and access the shared code?

I'm totally lost, I've tried a hundred different approaches and nothing works. Any help would be appreciated.

NOTE: appreciate any comments, but please explain like I'm 5!  A mini GitHub repo with 3 HelloWorld projects would be great!

Comment: have you thought of creating an npm package out of the shared code and import it when needed? keeping it as a seperate project

Comment: hey you can use `lerna` and `yarn` workspaces to achieve this

Comment: Thanks I need much more detail please.  I've tried EVERYTHING.

Comment: specifically what did you try? how did they fail?

Comment: "I've tried a hundred different approaches and nothing works" try harder. If you just google monorepo react typescript you'll have tons of working examples. (PS: I've recently started using `lerna` / `yarn workspaces` and there are many great articles around the internet :) )

Answer (score -1):

Install [Lerna](https://lerna.js.org/) and use it to manage the `shared` classes as packages. Read the documentation and don't be afraid to experiment with it.

If you want to see a Github repo that makes use of Lerna, there are quite a few, one of which is Facebook's Jest.

https://github.com/facebook/jest

Comment: I tried that but I have error in importing the shared module. What should be the module in tsconfig.json so that its supported by both frontend and backend?